# controlling display of latex equations in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, images

By default org-mode will overlap images of the latex equations for a given section, or for the whole document. If I press `C-c C-c` on an equation with an image overlay, all the images are removed. Can I make it so that only the one image is removed (and from which I can recreate the image by typing `C-c C-x C-l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that feature is present in org, but it's certainly possible to add it

```
(defun my-remove-latex-fragment-overlay-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((overlays (overlays-at (point))))
    (mapc (lambda (ov)
            (when (eq (overlay-get ov 'org-overlay-type) 'org-latex-overlay)
              (setq org-latex-fragment-image-overlays
                    (delete ov org-latex-fragment-image-overlays))
              (delete-overlay ov)))
          overlays)))
```

Calling that function will disable the overlay at point

Comment: It's probably more efficient to check each overlay with `(eq (overlay-get ov 'org-overlay-type) 'org-latex-overlay)` rather than linearly searching `org-latex-fragment-image-overlays`, especially if there are many equations in a document.

Comment: @lunaryorn you're absolutely right, sorry for being too lazy ! I edited the code to implement that

Comment: this works great!  How about retoggling the equations with `C-c C-x C-l`? Presumably all I need to do is navigate to the top of the buffer, execute the chord, and then return to the original point. Is there some elisp functionality that allows this?

Comment: @wdkrnls I might be missing something, but why do you want to go to the top of the buffer? `C-c C-x C-l` is supposed to (and does for me) work happily from the document's body

Comment: @Sigma: for me `C-c C-x C-l` removes all LaTeX overlays above the parent heading.

Comment: @wdkrnls oh I see, I did not understand that you wanted to operate globally. `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-l` might be closer to what you want. It's still a bid sad that the local `C-c C-x C-l` not only recomputes the overlay for the formula under the point, but also removes all the others. This probably calls for a full feature in org-mode to support partial recomputation properly.

Comment: Any updates on this? Has this been fixed in recent versions of emacs/org?